# Why does $\ln(1+\frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2}))=\frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})$?

Tags: logarithms

In order to show that a series converges, I want to show that $\sum\ln(\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n})$ Which led me to the following first part of the equation, but I didn't achieved to solve it so I looked in tha answer book for the second part wich I didn't understand...
why does

\begin{align*}
\ln(1+\frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2}))
&=\frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\ln(1+\frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})) = \frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2}) \\ \iff \\ 
\frac{\ln(1+\frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2}))}{\frac{3}{n^2}} = \frac{\frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})}{\frac{3}{n^2}} = 1 + \frac{o(\frac{1}{n^2})}{\frac{3}{n^2}} = 1+ 0 =1
$$
so you only need to prove
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2}))}{\frac{3}{n^2}} = 1$$
There are any workarounds here, but the simplest is probably using the [Mac Laurin series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), hence you get
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2}))}{\frac{3}{n^2}} = \frac{\frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})}{\frac{3}{n^2}} = 1 + \frac{o(\frac{1}{n^2})}{\frac{3}{n^2}} = 1+ 0 =1$$

Comment: Okay, but where does the following comes from $\ln(1+\frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})) = \frac{3}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})$?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} \ln(1+x) = x + o(x)$

Comment: sorry .. my mystake (typo)

Comment: Okay, I feel it.